# How to upload a file to AWS S3 from React using presigned URLs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, axios, boto3

The past two days really looked like hell as I was trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket.

1. I use a Python backend to generate presigned urls. I tried both `generate_presigned_url()` and `generate_presigned_post`. The former returns a url, the latter returns a json with many parameters.
2. The boto3 client is authorised using access keys of an IAM account with Full S3 permissions. The bucket in question has an allow-all policy and CORS config.
3. When I try to `axios.put()` or `axios.post()`, there are a ton of various errors that I get. They include:

- the enclosure type should be multiplart/form data
- not sufficient permissions
- AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidRequest The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

It doesn't make sense for me to post all the various versions of code that I had. But can anyone please point me to a nice tutorial that actually works or post some code snippets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. When authorising my `s3_client`, not only the keys should be provided, but also an additional config parameter:

```
s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3', 
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4',
        region_name = 'eu-west-2'),
    aws_access_key_id="AKIxxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxx"
)
```